# Adding an id on to a href jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the id of an radiobutton to be added to href when the link is clicked. I tried searching google for a long time. But maybe i'm missing because it's very basic.

I do have a bit of code written but it doesn't work. Help?

```
function ProductIDLink() {
        var url = "/bbbb/aaaaaaa/" + ('.aaasaff:radio:checked').attr('id');
        $("#safad").attr("href", url)
        }
```

Comment: alert your url and c what is wrondg in tat

Comment: @user1145009 - Please avoid txtspk on Stack Overflow.

Comment: $("#ProductOPT").attr("href", url); ";"missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've just forgotten a `$`:

```
...  ('.aaasaff:radio:checked').attr('id')
```

should be

```
... $('.aaasaff:radio:checked').attr('id')
```

Comment: Thank you! Works now! I can't believe I couldn't see that.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see the $ was missing.

```
function ProductIDLink() {
    var url = "/bbbb/aaaaaaa/" + $('.aaasaff:radio:checked').attr('id');
    $("#safad").attr("href", url)
    }
```